# The loss of logistic regression doesn't converge to 0

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I am doing a very simple logistic regression problem, but it doesn't converge. The dataset is linearly separable. There is no way that the loss can't converge to 0.

The loss converges very slowly and seems like converging to a constant. The gradient also doesn't converge to 0. I have checked the function of computing the gradient (by gradient checking) which is correct. The loss function should also be correct. And changing the learning rate doesn't help.

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(z):
    """ Sigmoid function """
    s = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
    return s


def cost_function(theta, X, y):

    output = sigmoid(np.dot(X, theta))
    cost = 0
    m_samples = len(y)
    for i in range(m_samples):
        if y[i] == 0:
            cost += -(1 - y[i]) * np.log(1 - output[i])
        elif y[i] == 1:
            cost += -y[i] * np.log(output[i])
    cost /= m_samples
    return cost


def gradient_update(theta, X, y):
    output = sigmoid(np.dot(X, theta))
    grad = np.dot((output - y).T, X)
    grad = grad / m_samples
    return grad


def gradient_descent(theta, X, y, alpha, max_iterations, print_iterations):

    m_samples = len(y)
    iteration = 0
    X_train = X / np.max(X)

    while (iteration < max_iterations):
        iteration += 1


        gradient = gradient_update(theta, X_train, y)
        theta = theta - alpha * gradient
        if iteration % print_iterations == 0 or iteration == 1:
            cost = cost_function(theta, X_train, y)
            print("[ Iteration", iteration, "]", "cost =", cost)
        #print(gradient)

num_features = train_X.shape[1]
initial_theta = np.random.randn(num_features)
max_iter = 200
print_iter = 25
alpha_test = 0.1

learned_theta = gradient_descent(initial_theta, train_X, train_y, alpha_test, max_iter, print_iter)
```

I don't think it converges that slowly instead it should converge very fast.

This is the output.

[ Iteration 1 ] cost = 0.6321735730663283

[ Iteration 25 ] cost = 0.6307985058882454

[ Iteration 50 ] cost = 0.6302278288232466

[ Iteration 75 ] cost = 0.6300077925064239

[ Iteration 100 ] cost = 0.6299228901862299

[ Iteration 125 ] cost = 0.6298894960439918

[ Iteration 150 ] cost = 0.6298756287152963

[ Iteration 175 ] cost = 0.6298691634248297

[ Iteration 200 ] cost = 0.6298655267069331

I don't know what's going on.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239928/is-there-any-intuitive-explanation-of-why-logistic-regression-will-not-work-for

Comment: I don't see your data. Did you have bias in your parameters? The extra column of 1s?